# migrate filter for specific antMatchers to spring-security 6

Tags: spring-security, migration, spring-security-6

I am currently in the process of migrating our services to spring boot 3 with spring security 6.

While doing so I am currently hanging on the problem, that I want to establish a filter only for one set of endpoints:

```
  @Bean
  @Order(10)
  SecurityFilterChain internalEndpointsFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/cache/**") <<<-- Problem
        .addFilterBefore(sharedSecretAuthenticationFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter)
        .exceptionHandling({ exceptionHandling ->
          exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthorizedAuthenticationEntryPoint())
        })
        .authorizeRequests({ authorizeRequests ->
          authorizeRequests.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        })
        .build()
  }
```

When I migrate whatever I change here I just always get a 401 for those endpoints.

My try:

```
    http.csrf { it.disable() }
        .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS) }
        .securityMatcher("/cache/**")
        .addFilterBefore(sharedSecretAuthenticationFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter)
        .exceptionHandling({ exceptionHandling ->
          exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthorizedAuthenticationEntryPoint())
        })
        .authorizeHttpRequests({ authorizeRequests ->
          authorizeRequests
              .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        })
        .build()
```

Edit after comment:
It is important that we need to tie this security chain to the regex above as we have a different chain for the rest of the endpoints, which is configured in a lib and included in our service:

```
  @Bean
  @Order(10)
  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(oauthAuthenticationFilter(jwtProcessor), LogoutFilter)
        .addFilterAfter(authenticationLessModeAuthenticationFilter(), OAuthAuthenticationFilter)
        .exceptionHandling({ exceptionHandling ->
          exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthorizedAuthenticationEntryPoint())
        })
        .authorizeHttpRequests({ authorizeRequests ->
          authorizeRequests
              .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/error")).permitAll()
              .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        })
        .build()
  }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the problem is in migration and before you did it all worked great the problem is in `internalEndpointsFilterChain` configuration.

Based on [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#_request_matchers)

**UPDATE**

Can you try next one implementation and give me a feedback if it help you.

```
  @Bean
  @Order(10)
  SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.sessionManagement(sessionAuthenticationStrategy ->
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.securityMatcher("/cache/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request ->
            request.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated());
    http.addFilterBefore(sharedSecretAuthenticationFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);
    http.exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthorizedAuthenticationEntryPoint()));

    return http.build();
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still ends up in a 401. We have the problem that we have multiple securityFilterChains. I think here it is important to tie the security to the regex mentioned above so later security filters do not override it.

If I understand it correctly, they are chained and so here we need to say "this is only for `/cache/**`, for the rest use a different security chain

Comment: just a second i`m going to update the answer

Comment: I did add some information about our other security filter chain

Comment: i have just added the right way to do it.

Comment: another thing is to change the `@Order(10)` to higher one or less depends on requirements.

Comment: thank you so much, that - together with lowering the order - worked :) I wonder why the same order worked before the migration (: